# https kubernetes deployed application

Tags: azure, ssl, https, kubernetes

I am using following document to implement https on kubernetes deployed application :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls

I am getting  "Certificate does not exist" . i have used cluster issuer and "letsencrypt-prod" . i have following certificates :

acme-crt
acme-crt-secret
cert-mgr-webhook-ca
cert-mgr-webhook-webhook-tls
tls-secret

why i am getting "certificate does not exist" when i describe certificate ?

```
`Name:         acme-crt-secret
Namespace:    <name-space>
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-07-19T07:41:46Z
  Generation:          2
  Owner References:
    API Version:           extensions/v1beta1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  starc
    UID:                   <Id>
  Resource Version:        <version>
  Self Link:               /apis/certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/<name-space>/certificates/acme-crt-secret
  UID:                     <Uid>
Spec:
  Acme:
    Config:
      Domains:
        starcapp.com
      Http 01:
        Ingress:
        Ingress Class:  nginx
  Dns Names:
    starcapp.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-prod
  Secret Name:  acme-crt-secret
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2019-07-19T07:41:46Z
    Message:               Certificate does not exist
    Reason:                NotFound
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>`
```

Comment: show your ingress definition

Comment: and, show the actual output

Comment: updated response of kubectl describe certificate

Comment: Do you create the crds and the cert-manager?

Comment: yes i created . i wanna know is this paid certificate ?

Comment: No, it's free. I can create the certificate without the error. But I do not know what steps you have done.

Comment: i have followed following link 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls?WT.mc_id=stackoverflow-stackoverflow-nepeters

Comment: The steps are right in the link and I just create the certificate with the steps install cert-manager, create cluster issuer and create a certificate and there is no error. So maybe you did something wrong in the steps.

Comment: i already have ingress deployed so i have to deploy it again after getting certificate ? or should i go with these 3 steps only and update ingress with TLS settings

Comment: As I think, the ingress does not affect creating the certificates. So you just need to recreate the certificates following the 3 steps.

Comment: I have deleted cert manager and certificate and repeated these 3 steps . On repeating these steps i got certificate sucessfully but its self signed even though i used letsencrypt-prod .
Events:

  Normal  GenerateSelfSigned  12m   cert-manager  Generated temporary self signed certificate
completed successfully
  Normal  CertIssued          11m   cert-manager  Certificate issued successfully

Comment: You can take a look at the [Issuer types](https://cert-manager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/issuers.html#supported-issuer-types), maybe you can use the type ACME.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify namespace in your certificate configuration file.

Look at example ertificate configuration file:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: tls-secret
```

> namespace: ingress-basic

```
spec:
  secretName: tls-secret-staging
  dnsNames:
  - demo-aks-ingress.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
  acme:
    config:
    - http01:
        ingressClass: nginx
      domains:
      - demo-aks-ingress.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

Then exec command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f your-certificate-filename.yaml
```

Make sure the secret is in the cert-manager namespace.

Create a certificate manual as well. Once you 'forced' cert-manager to create a certificate, he was good to go en auto created certificates as well.

Comment: namespace is already present at tls-secret and acme-crt but in the end of both files same warning "Certificate does not exist"